# Как запустить Putty по serial (COM) порту в Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, com, serial, putty

Столкнулся в Ubuntu "механический бобер" с проблемой.
Запускаю Putty SSH клиент(гуевский чтоб мышкой всё "набирать") выбираю вкладку serial. Ввожу адрес  `/dev/ttyUSB0`  нажимаю `open` и выводит мне ошибку:

> Unable to open connection to /dev/ttyUSB0:
>
> Unable to open serial port

Проверяю аппарат в папке dev и правда есть файл `/dev/ttyUSB0` при выдергивании провода он исчезает, при этом также появляються и исчезают папки `/dev/serial/by-id` и `/dev/serial/by-path` в каждой из них по файлу в общем как положено.

Подумал аппарат "брешит" решил по отправлять на него сообщения (фиг знает зачем)

```
echo ":0101010000" > /dev/ttyUSB0
bash: /dev/ttyUSB0: Отказано в доступе

echo ":0101010000" > /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_AI05HLY6-if00-port0
bash: /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_AI05HLY6-if00-port0: Отказано в доступе
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем удивительно но надо было всего навсего воспользоваться консолью и ввести команду

```
sudo putty /dev/ttyUSB0 -serial -sercfg 9600,8,n,1,N
```

---

*Вы скажете слишком мало для ответа и по сути это не вопрос, не спорю НО я пол дня бился с этой хренью (всё на аппарат "грешил"), а на саммом деле думаю был слишком приучен работать по виндусовски по этому и "пугаюсь" консоли. И да удивило Гуишка не сработала , а консоль сработала :3*

Comment: а ещё лучше посмотреть, какая у устройства группа и добавить своего пользователя в неё (не забыв перелогиниться)...

Comment: @FatZer, перелогиниваться не обязательно, если знать команду *newgrp*.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo adduser имя dialout
$ sudo reboot
```

ГУИ Путти заработает как требуется